# How to scale the margin like size scales with flex-grow?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a card with squares in it, and i need that the margin in the squares scales like the size scales when i use flex-grow.

I need to place the squares inside a div, but they all need to fit when i change the number of squares.

I can scale the size of the squares with flex-grow, but i need to control the margin of them too. Because the margin when there are 8 and 10 squares is diferent for them to fit.

html :

```
<div id="card">
      <div id="descriptionZone">
      </div>
      <div id="squaresZone">
        <div id="squares" *ngFor="let number of orders; let i= index">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="brandZone">
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#squaresZone{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: #1e2023 solid 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#squares{
  //height: 100px;
  //width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: solid wheat 1px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  min-width: 69px;
  min-height: 69px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  ma
```

rgin-right: 25px;
margin-top: 10px
}

I am trying and trying, but cant seem to find a solution to scale the margin that i need.

for exemple, when there are 8 squares, i need the margin-left and margin-right to be 15px and when there are 10, i need it to be 25px

Is there any way to scale the margin?

Comment: you can `justify-content: space-around` to have even space between each element as well as a border, or `justify-content: space-between` to have them flush on the edges but space between them. You can also try percentage values, or vw values.

Comment: That dont work, because the margin still needs to be diferent when per exemple i have 6 squares. 3 on top and 2 at the bottom